# How to make a conditional based of span text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have my span like this:

```
<span class="lunch" id="foods"> My fruits </span>
```

And another span like this:

```
<span class="lunch" id="food"> apple </span>
```

How can I make it so when the "My fruits" text on the first span changes to for example, "My sweets"(this change occurs by changing the content on the same tab), the text on the other span changes from apple to "chocolate bar" or something like that?

I´ve tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(document.getElementById("foods").value=="My sweets")
 document.getELementById("food").textContent="chocolate";
</script>
```

But nothing happens.

Each span is inside a respective div with it's respective id

Sorry for the stupid example but I don´t know how to explain it better right now. Does someone know how I could make this change?

Comment: This code only runs when the page is loaded; you need to invoke it when the change happens.

Comment: Can you tell us how the text inside <span id="foods"> changes??

Comment: @ScottHunter how could I do that?

Comment: Rinxs we need to know what code exactly causes your foods span to change from "My fruits" to "My sweets". Is it the click of a button? Some input field? An API call of some sort?

Comment: @YeshwinVerma it all occurs in the same tab, but the content of that tab changes according to your selection on a list, when you enter on the first element of the list, the span text says to put it on the example, "My fruits", when you go back and select the other element on the list, it would now say "My sweets"

Comment: Rinxs so then this "change" event that puts the value from the list into your foods span would also perform a check on the value to decide what to put in the other span as well.

Comment: As already pointed out there's a typo in `getELementById`. Also, you can't get the content of a `<span>` by using `.value`. This would be for `input` elements and so on. Use (as you already did) either `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`. Further, you have a leading and trailing space in your `<span>` element, while you do not have this in your `if` statement. Finally, you may need to invoke it as **@scott-hunter** suggested. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4nj3vg0b/  (the button only simulates the tab/list change).

Answer (score 2):

To make it work, you have to use a[`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) to watch content change.

```js
function mutation(mutations) {
  if(document.getElementById("foods").textContent=="My sweets"){
    document.getElementById("food").textContent="chocolate";
  }
};

var target = document.getElementById("foods")
var observer = new MutationObserver( mutation );
var config = { characterData: false, attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };

observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<span class="lunch" id="foods">My fruits</span>
<br>
<span class="lunch" id="food">apple</span>
<br><br>
<button onClick='document.getElementById("foods").textContent="My sweets"'>Change content</button>
```

Comment: "...when the "My fruits" text on the first span changes..."